# Extracting Data with .selectitem VBA-SAP

Tags: excel, vba, sapui5

I am trying to extract the text from a topdown analysis in SAP using VBA. I basically need to move down the column, evaluate if the extracted text contains a certain character string, then extract the cell adjacent to it.

**First:** Does anyone know how to change this line of code (the script for that specific cell) so that I can extract its text to a variable rather than just select it?

**Second:** Does anyone know how to make this line variable using `i` as the variable?

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          5", "C         35"
```

Comment: sapui5 is a javascript framework. are you extracting this from a website somehow or from an RFC call

Answer (score 2):

In similar cases, I proceeded as follows:

```
myRow  = right(space(10) & cstr(i) , 11) 
myText = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").getItemText(myRow ,"C         35")
```

Regards,
ScriptMan